# HTA can't run ie4uinit.exe

Tags: windows, permissions, vbscript

I'm trying to refresh desktop icons from an HTA using the following:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.run("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ie4uinit.exe -show");
```

I'm running it as **administrator** and I'm positive `C:\Windows\System32\ie4uinit.exe` exists.

If I use the exactly same command from a vbscript `.vbs` it runs the file successfuly.

Is it some kind of restriction? Why HTA can't run `C:\Windows\System32\ie4uinit.exe` ?

The error message:

[image]

How can I make this work?

Comment: So what is the error message when it doesn't work?

Comment: I updated the question with the error screen.

Comment: It still seems to me that 32-bit redirection can account for ie4uinit not found. Are you sure you are executing in 64-bit mode at the moment the dialog is displayed?

Comment: Positive. 64bit. I checked the proccess image in the task manager.

Comment: What happens when you run as System using `psexec -i -s`? As another test enable for your account [Bypass traverse checking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/bypass-traverse-checking).

Comment: Could you also show the contents of the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\htafile\Shell\Open\Command` and the header tags of your HTML.

Comment: The reg key contains: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe "%1" {1A460BD7-F1C3-4B2E-88BF-4E770A288AF5}%U{1A460BD7-F1C3-4B2E-88BF-4E770A288AF5} %*`

Comment: This is the 32-bit HTA handler : `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe` - **SysWOW64**. It looks more and more like redirection is the answer, even if by some unknown magic the dialog is produced by a 64-bit task. You might try using `C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe`, but it might break some stuff - there is a reason for the 32-bit version being the default handler.

Answer (score 0):

Your registry key of
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\htafile\Shell\Open\Command`
contains the value of :

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe "%1" {1A460BD7-F1C3-4B2E-88BF-4E770A288AF5}%U{1A460BD7-F1C3-4B2E-88BF-4E770A288AF5} %*
```

The is the 32-bit HTA handler, which means that you are running in 32-bit
mode.

This further means that you are using the 32-bit version of VBScript,
so that Windows file redirection is actually causing it to look in
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, where `ie4uinit.exe` does not exist.

A solution to avoid maintaining two different
versions of your VBScript scripts is to be found in this
[ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/811734/18736).

Alternatively, you might try starting your application using
the 64-bit HTA handler, found at `C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe`.

You should be aware of the fact that Microsoft is no longer actively
supporting HTA applications, preferring instead to concentrate on
Windows Forms and similar technologies, so it is quite likely that
HTA will become deprecated some time in the future.

Comment: All 64bit here. Still not that. I've given the full path to `ie4uinit.exe`

Comment: Task Manager in Windows 10 no longer shows the 32- and 64-bitness of a process. You need Process Explorer for that, showing the Image Type column, or double-click the exe and see it in the Image field.

Comment: You may still in theory access the real system32 by using the [File System Redirector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector) : `C:\Windows\Sysnative\ie4uinit.exe`, although I don't know how well this will work in your environment. Note that `Sysnative` is not a directory, only a traversal tool, and that it doesn't exist for 64-bit apps.

Comment: @Azevedo: Any comments?

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: It will stay the same as long as you run in 32-bit mode. The link I gave has a solution which I haven't tested.

Comment: Do you still have some misgivings about the correctness of my answer?